# How to find all 'duplicate symbol' errors in a project at once

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, compiler-errors

I currently had this problem, that after adding a framework (in my case Sharekit), I get dozens of these 'duplicate symbol' errors. I wonder id there is a good why to find them all at once? Currently I clean/build and then find another class/symbol that has a duplicate symbol. Finding them all at once would really speed up this painful cleanup process.

Many thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, you end up compiling (and then linking) a file twice. In that case: Delete all the library's source files from your project (and also from any dependencies). Then re-add them to your app… or you could just create a static lib and link to that (once).

Otherwise, some more specifics as to why there are duplicates in the first place might help us narrow it down.